# Playframework 2.4 issue

Tags: java, playframework

I am trying to build application on Playframework 2.4. I am getting this exceptions. kindly help and oblige.

```
play.http.errorHandler [utils.ErrorHandler] was not loaded.
No source available, here is the exception stack trace:

->java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: utils.ErrorHandler

     java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)

     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)

     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

     play.utils.Reflect$.loadClass$1(Reflect.scala:93)

     play.utils.Reflect$.configuredClass(Reflect.scala:112)

     play.utils.Reflect$.bindingsFromConfiguration(Reflect.scala:46)

     play.api.http.HttpErrorHandler$.bindingsFromConfiguration(HttpErrorHandler.scala:52)

     play.api.inject.BuiltinModule$$anonfun$bindings$3.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:50)

     play.api.inject.BuiltinModule$$anonfun$bindings$3.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:50)

     play.api.inject.BuiltinModule$$anonfun$dynamicBindings$1$1.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:25)

     play.api.inject.BuiltinModule$$anonfun$dynamicBindings$1$1.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:25)

     scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:252)

     scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:252)
 scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)

 scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)

 scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:252)

 scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)

 play.api.inject.BuiltinModule.dynamicBindings$1(BuiltinModule.scala:25)

 play.api.inject.BuiltinModule.bindings(BuiltinModule.scala:49)

 play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$class.guice(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:264)

 play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModule$.guice(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:200)

 play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$3$$anonfun$guiced$2.apply(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:244)

 play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$3$$anonfun$guiced$2.apply(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:244)

 scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)

 scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)

 scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)

 scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)

 scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)

 play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$3.guiced(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:244)

 play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModule$$anonfun$guiced$1.apply(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:222)

 play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModule$$anonfun$guiced$1.apply(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:222)

 scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:252)

 scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:252)

 scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)

 scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:252)

 scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)

 play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModule$.guiced(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:222)

 play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.createModule(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:116)

 play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.applicationModule(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:87)

 play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:126)

 play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:93)

 play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)

 play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:153)

 play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:150)

 play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)

 play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:150)

 play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)

 scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)

 play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)

 play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119)

 scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:230)

 play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119)

 play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:111)

 scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)

 scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)

 java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)

 java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)

 java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)

 java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1689)

 java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Comment: Showing the stackframe can indeed be of some use. But without the code and without explaining what you were trying to do, we can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have a look at the `play.http.errorHandler` property in `conf/application.conf` which it looks like is pointing to `utils.ErrorHandler` that wasn't compiled and included.

I'd check whether `ErrorHandler` is present in `app/utils`, whether it compiles ok, and also doing an `./activator clean` before trying again.

I hope you manage to get it working and get to spend time with the awesome 2.4 version :) and most importantly, let us know how you got it working in the end. ;)